# No data when running SELECT from C# OracleDB

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a C# application that reads from a Oracle DB, but gets no data in my application. If I am running the same SELECT statement directly from the management tool, it returns the data fine.

```
static void Selectexample()
    {
       string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;user id=system;password=123456";


       DbProviderFactory dbFactory= DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OracleClient"); 

        DbConnection con = dbFactory.CreateConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connStr;

        string sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM person";

        DbCommand cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;


        try
        {   
            con.Open();


            DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            string headline = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string s = reader.GetName(i);
                headline += s.PadLeft(20) + " | ";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(headline);


            while (reader.Read())
            {

                string line = "";
                string s1 = (string)reader[0];
                string s2 = (string)reader[1];

                line += ("");
                line += s1.PadLeft(20) + " | ";
                line += s2.PadLeft(20) + " | ";

                Console.WriteLine(line);

            }
        }
        catch (DbException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fejl: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {   
            con.Close();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("---");
    }
```

Table definition for Person:

```
create table person
(
cpr char(10) primary key,
name varchar(25),
job varchar(25),
salary int,
zip char(4),
foreign key (zip) references zipcode(zip)
);
```

I am running .Net 3.0 with x86 Oracle driver on x64 Windows

Comment: At a glance the code looks fine. Does the headlines get printed? Have you set a breakpoint inside the while(reader.Read()) loop? If so does that breakpoint ever get hit?

Comment: step through the debugger.  whats the output of the above code to console?

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies in getting a successful connection to the database. The connection string specifies "Data Source=localhost". Do you have a database named "localhost" set up in TNSnames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for their suggestions. It turned out to be the Management Studio does not commit data right after an insert. You have to close the tool before it commits data. Now my data are displayed in my application.

Comment: In SqlServer Management Studio, if you update data you have to move the cursor to antoher row, or re-run the select query, to insert / update data. It might be the same in oracle